Confusion in using applying variance formula
Consider the question
An elevator’s weight capacity is 1000 pounds. Three men and three women are riding the elevator. Adult male weight is normally distributed with mean 172 pounds and standard deviation 29 pounds. Adult female weight is normally distributed with mean 143 pounds and standard deviation 29 pounds. Find the probability that the passengers’ total weight exceeds the elevator’s capacity.
My mind went into 2 direction
First I defined $T$ to denote the Total Weight.
The samples are $M1, M2, M3, F1, F2, F3$. Total weight is distributed as sum where $Mi$ are iid and $Fi$ are iid.
$$T= M1+M2+M3+F1+F2+F3$$
Here is where the confusion is
$E(T)= E(M1)+E(M2)+E(M3)+E(F1)+E(F2)+E(F3)$,
$Var(T)=Var(M1)+Var(M2)+Var(M3)+Var(F1)+Var(F2)+Var(F3)$,
$STD(T) = \sqrt{Var(T)}$.
However if i define $T=3M+3F$, $E(T)$ remains unchanged however $Var(T)$ takes up the value of $9Var(M)+9Var(F)$, and $STD(T) = \sqrt{Var(T)}$
Which method is correct?

The variance of a sum of independent random variables $X$ and $Y$ is the sum of their variances; i.e.,
$$\operatorname{Var}[X+Y] \overset{\text{ind}}{=} \operatorname{Var}[X] + \operatorname{Var}[Y],$$
where the "ind" over the $=$ symbol means that the equality holds when $X$ and $Y$ are independent.
Hence, if $X$ and $Y$ are also identically distributed, then they have the same variance, i.e. $\operatorname{Var}[X] = \operatorname{Var}[Y]$, so the variance of the sum is equal to twice the variance of a single variable:
$$\operatorname{Var}[X+Y] \overset{\text{iid}}{=} 2 \operatorname{Var}[X] = 2 \operatorname{Var}[Y].$$
Here, "iid" means that $X$ and $Y$ are independent and identically distributed.
The source of your confusion is that the sum of iid random variables $X$ and $Y$ is not the same thing as twice the value of $X$.  For instance, if $X$ represents the outcome of a single roll of a fair six-sided die, and $Y$ represents the outcome of another single roll of the same die, then $X$ and $Y$ are iid but $X+Y \ne 2X$.  After all, why should it?  $X$ and $Y$ are allowed to take on different outcomes; e.g., $(X,Y) = (3,4)$ is one possible outcome of two consecutive rolls of a fair die.  But what does $2X$ mean?  It means to roll the die once, and then multiply its outcome by $2$.  So it is impossible for $2X$ to be an odd number, yet $X+Y = 7$ is certainly possible.
This is why the formula
$$\operatorname{Var}[X+Y] \overset{\text{iid}}{=} 2 \operatorname{Var}[X]$$
is not the same as
$$\operatorname{Var}[2X] = 4 \operatorname{Var}[X].$$
Now, relating this to your specific problem, what would you be calculating if you had used
$$\operatorname{Var}[3M + 3F] = 9\operatorname{Var}[M] + 9\operatorname{Var}[F]?$$
What you would be doing is taking the weight of one man, and the weight of one woman, multiplying these by $3$ to represent the total weight of all six people, and then calculating the variance.  And you can see that this is completely wrong.  The correct way to compute the total weight is to take each person's weight and add them up.  The three men do not necessarily have the same weight, even though their weights are random variables that are identically distributed, just as in the die roll example.  And the same is true of the three women.
Therefore, your first formula for the variance is correct:
$$\operatorname{Var}[T] = \operatorname{Var}[M_1] + \operatorname{Var}[M_2] + \operatorname{Var}[M_3] + \operatorname{Var}[F_1] + \operatorname{Var}[F_2] + \operatorname{Var}[F_3]$$
and because $M_1, M_2, M_3$ are iid, and $F_1, F_2, F_3$ are iid, it follows that
$$\operatorname{Var}[T] = 3\sigma_M^2 + 3\sigma_F^2,$$
where $\sigma_M^2 = 29^2$ is the variance of the weight of men, and $\sigma_F^2 = 29^2$ is the variance of the weight of women.  These just happen to be the same between men and women, as stated by the problem, but the mean weight of men and women are not the same.

The first approach is the correct one.
In the second approach $T=3M+3T$, the variance of $T$ included covariances among the terms, i.e., anyone is perfectly correlated with him/her-self.
For example, $$\begin{align}
\mathbb{V}\text{ar}(3M) &= \mathbb{V}\text{ar}(M+M+M)\\
&=\mathbb{V}\text{ar}(M) + \mathbb{V}\text{ar}(M) + \mathbb{V}\text{ar}(3M) \\
& \quad+2\mathbb{C}\text{ov}(M,M)+2\mathbb{C}\text{ov}(M,M)+2\mathbb{C}\text{ov}(M,M)
\\&=9\mathbb{V}\text{ar}(M). \end{align}$$
However, for three independent men, their covariances are 0:
$$\begin{align}
& \mathbb{V}\text{ar}(M1+M2+M3)\\
&=\mathbb{V}\text{ar}(M1) + \mathbb{V}\text{ar}(M2) + \mathbb{V}\text{ar}(M2) \\
& \quad+2\mathbb{C}\text{ov}(M1,M2)+2\mathbb{C}\text{ov}(M1,M3)+2\mathbb{C}\text{ov}(M2,M3)
\\&=3\mathbb{V}\text{ar}(M1)+0+0+0. \end{align}$$
